# If I uninstall StarCraft 2 from my old computer, will I be able to install it on a new one?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have StarCraft II installed on my old laptop right now. I want to install it on my new computer as well. If I uninstall it from my old computer, will I be able to install it on the new one?

I don't care about my campaign progress.

Answer (score 10):

If you still have the Starcraft 2 Disc all you need to do is install it onto the new computer like you did originally.

You do not have to uninstall the copy on your laptop, but you'll be unable to run starcraft 2 from both computers simultaneously (unless you're using offline mode).

If you have lost your starcraft 2 discs, you can install the game via digital download through battle.net, [here:](https://us.battle.net/account/management/sc2/dashboard.html?accountName=SCII-1&region=US)

Comment: That link might only work for US residents... let me know if the link takes you someplace weird.

Comment: You can run multiple instances installed from the same CD on multiple computers at the same time.  What you can't do is log into the same account from two computers at once.

Comment: @StrixVaria exactly, hence "(unless you're using offline mode)"

Answer (score 6):

Unless you want to free up space, you don't have to uninstall the game at all. You're [perfectly entitled](http://us.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_US&articleId=30800&pageNumber=1&searchQuery=copies) to install the game on multiple computers as you'll only be able to play on one at a time. Additionally your campaign progress should be retained without any intervention on your part (it's saved in the cloud).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is your serial key, but even with it I don't recall that you need it to install Starcraft 2, since it is already linked to your battle.net account

Here is the link for [EU PC version](https://eu.battle.net/account/management/sc2/download.html?gameRegion=EU&lang=en-GB&platform=win) and the link for the [EU Mac Version](https://eu.battle.net/account/management/sc2/download.html?gameRegion=EU&lang=en-GB&platform=mac)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to uninstall it, you can install it on many PCs, because it's your battle.net account which allows you to play in multiplayer and to save progress.

And the progress is saved in the cloud, so don't worry about achievements.