# Playing SC2 Replays with double click

Tags: starcraft-2

When I double-click on an SC2replay file in brings up SC2 but then nothing happens.  How can I get it to play the replay?

I am trying with a replay that's relatively recent... from April.

I'm on Windows 7 x64.

EDIT: It **does not** give any sort of error message as far as I can tell.

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but have you logged into SC2 after launching the replay file? After logging in, the replay launches just fine for me here.

Comment: I've had similar problems... except I cannot open them entirely...

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63002/replays-stopped-working

Comment: @Sorean yes, I logged in when sc2 launched. It didn't play the replay.  I suspect Ampersand might be right about it being from an earlier patch, I will test tonight when I get home and see if I can get it working with one of my own replays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the replay is from a previous patch, which can cause this issue.

You can view the replay by placing it in the replays folder located here:
`%username%\Documents\StarCraft II\Accounts\xxxxxxxx\x-xx-x-xxxxxxx\Replays\Multiplayer`
There should be a shortcut in the `StarCraft II` folder pointing to your account.
You can then access the replay in-game.

StarCraft II will load into the previous patch and play the replay. Note that you will be offline on Battle.net while viewing an old replay.

Comment: You are right, it was the patch.  It worked when I used more recent replays.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot launch replays from outside of Starcraft 2 if it is already running. If you close SC2 completely (not just minimize) and then double-click the replay, SC2 should launch and start the replay after you log in but if you then try to do the same with another replay while SC2 is still running, it will just bring SC2 to the front without actually doing something.

As Ampersand noted in his answer, you can put replays into the SC2 replay folder

```
%username%\Documents\StarCraft II\Accounts\xxxxxxxx\x-xx-x-xxxxxxx\Replays\Multiplayer
```

if you want to watch multiple replays in a row. If i remember correctly, there is also a button on the replay screen that opens the replay folder in the windows explorer if you can't find the correct folder.

Comment: +1 Sure enough, it doesn't work if SC2 is already running.  Seems like it would be a nice feature to implement -- but for now I'll just keep the replay folder open.