# How to watch Replays with double click after copying the install folder to new computer?

Tags: starcraft-2

I copied my Starcraft 2 install directory to a new computer, so I don't have to download all the patches again. Everything works fine, except when I double click on a Replay it does not open Starcraft 2.

I tried messing with the registry exporting some of entries from my main computer, but it does not work.

This problem has nothing to do with this question: [playing sc2 replays with double click](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65578/playing-sc2-replays-with-double-click) as it is solved, but it does not work for me.

I copied a recent replay from my replays folder into C:\Temp. I closed Starcraft 2. I doubleclicked the replay and got stuck in the Starcraft 2 main screen after logging in (where you select the game mode). This works on my main computer though and the replay starts as expected.

I even tried to open the replay in my console with the following command but it does not work either.

```
"C:\Games\StarCraft II\StarCraft II.exe" "C:\Temp\Discord IV (279).SC2Replay"
```

Comment: Just a side note, not an final solution: The tool sc2gears has the function to open replays included and also offers search functionality and stuff, so it might work as workaround: https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the 1.5 patch, "StarCraft II.exe" no longer launches replays if passed as an argument. Instead there is a file "Support/SC2Switcher.exe" in the StarCraft II folder. If you pass a replay to that, it will be started (assumed SC2 is not running when you do it). So if you associate SC2Replay files with this exe, it will work.

Some more info on this: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=357501&currentpage=12#235

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem may be that you copied the files over, but for some reason the file association didn't get set. To check this, open up your Command Prompt and type "assoc .SC2Replay". It should return ".SC2Replay=[SC2 executable]" (I'm not sure what the executable is named). If it doesn't say that, type "assoc .SC2Replay=[SC2 executable]", and that should fix it, if that's the problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just executed the same commands on my PC (which has file associations for SC2 replays set up) and got no output from the `assoc` command. ("File association not found for extension .SC2Replay")

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh Really? Hmm, that's odd. That is the correct extension, is it not?

Comment: Yes it is, which is particularly confusing. I even double-clicked-to-launch-ed a .SC2Replay file from my My Documents folder right after to make sure the association was valid.

Comment: I already have this association and this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Well, darn. I'm afraid I won't be much help then. I don't have SC2, I was just going off of Windows knowledge.